# Build JSON API for WooCommerce Orders with Python

Tags: python, json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am a beginner, struggling to write my JSON API.
The API should export all new incoming orders which have the status "on-hold".

But how can I save all the exported order ID's in an Array?
After the export, I want to update all the exported orders and set the status to "completed".

My Code:

```
from woocommerce import API
import json

wcapi = API(
    url="https://example.de/",
    consumer_key="ck_1234567891234567891324567891324568791",
    consumer_secret="cs_1234567891234567891324567891324568791",
    wp_api=True,
    version="wc/v3"
)

wcorders = wcapi.get("orders", params={"status": "on-hold"}).json()

print(json.dumps(wcorders, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

if wcorders == []:
    print("No new orders")
    
elif wcorders != []:
    data = {
        "update": [
            {
                "id": "2620",
                "status": "completed"
            }
        ],
    }

    wcorders_update = wcapi.post("orders/batch", data).json()
    print(json.dumps(wcorders_update, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
    print("Orders have been imported and status has been set to 'completed'.")
```

I would highly appreciate if you can help me :-)

Thank you in advance!
Best Regards